# Where does dmidecode get the SMBIOS table?

Tags: linux, x86, bios

I always have this question and didn't get an answer after reading man-page and searching online. Anyone who has knowledge about this please comment.

I understand that SMBIOS table or DMI table is what dmidecode locates and parses. But where does it get it from? Is it in the format of a file in Linux?

Answer (score 10):

Looks like it comes from /dev/mem

```
root@aw42e ~]# strace -F -e open dmidecode -t 17
   <snip>
    open("/sys/firmware/efi/systab", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/proc/efi/systab", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY)              = 3
    SMBIOS 2.5 present.

    open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY)              = 3
    Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
    Memory Device
<snip>
```

`/dev/mem` is described as

> mem is a character device file that is an image of the main memory of
>   the computer. It may be used, for example, to examine (and even patch)
>   the system. Byte addresses in mem are interpreted as physical memory
>   addresses.

So to answer, it is contained in /dev/mem

I'm searching for more info, but I assume that the kernel inserts the DMI table into memory at boot time - from `man dmidecode`

> As  you  run  it,  dmidecode will try to locate the DMI table. If it
>   succeeds, it will then parse this table and
>          display a list of records like this one:

Comment: `/dev/mem` doesn't seem to be the only location where `dmidecode` queries, in my case it mainly if not only extracts information from two files inside `/sys/firmware/dmi/tables` which are `smbios_entry_point` and `DMI`.

Answer (score 7):

The data defined in the DMI table is an industry standard; implemented for both Linux and Windows (among other PC OSs):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS
>
> the System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) specification defines data
> structures (and access methods) that can be used to read information
> stored in the BIOS of a computer. Circa 1999, it became part of the
> domain of the Distributed Management Task Force (DMTF)...
>
> At approximately the same time Microsoft started to require that OEMs
> and BIOS vendors support the interface/data-set in order to have
> Microsoft certification...

You can read more about the Linux implementation - and the driver used to export the actual, raw data to userspace ("/sys/class/dmi/", "/dev/mem", and friends) - here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160318010215/http://www.linux.org/threads/the-linux-kernel-configuring-the-kernel-part-19.4929/

The actual kernel code for accessing DMI info is here (your distro/version might differ):

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/firmware/dmi-sysfs.c

Answer (score 1):

SMBIOS standart defined by DMTF. You can find related pdf at https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios/

SMBIOS can be 32bit or 64bit regardless of cpu arch. Like an 64bit system can have 32bit smbios structures. Spec ver 3.7.0 describes location of smbios at 5.2.1 (for 32bit) and 5.2.2 (for 64bit).

Note: **UEFI** bios and **Legacy** bios different has different locations for smbios. If bios is legacy you seek for `_SM_` (for 32bit) or `_SM3_` (for 64bit) at memory between **0xF0000-0xFFFFF**. You should seek both `_SM_` and `_SM3_`. UEFI is very interesting. UEFI provides a `system_table` interface for uefi application entry point. This is a ms c structure (byte alignments are different). this structure has an array of several tables like ACPI, SAL, SMBIOS etc. For finding smbios structure you search related guid for v2 or v3 smbios structure.

After finding smbios structure, you should parse with help of version. v2 and v3 has different structure layout. smbios structure gives you the pointer of the data array.

Linux kernel cache that array into sysfs.

**dmidecode** uses cached data or seeks data as described above.

This array is parsed with the spec dmtf provides (i mentioned the link above).