# C/C++ API for dmidecode

Tags: c++, c, linux

`dmidecode` lists various hardware parameters, including size, model, and serial numbers of the actual DRAM modules installed.

Without using `system()` and parsing the output text, is there a programmatic interface to obtain the same information via C/C++?

For example:

```
dmidecode --type 17
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0043, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0042
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: 0711
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: PUD31600C114G2VS
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0044, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0042
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
```

Comment: `/proc` and `/sys` may have what you need. Also see [Get hardware information from existed files in Linux using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44382885/608639) and friends.

Comment: Good tip.  `/sys` seems to have the information, but the linked article suggests reverse engineering `dmidecode.c` or `lshw`.  Was wondering if there is a more, umm, defined API.  But can reverse engineer if need be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that dmidecode gets data from these binary files
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point

There's a library for parsing them
https://github.com/brunexgeek/smbios-parser

For me it did the trick. The only inconsistency I encountered is with getting UUID of the system. Apparently it's because at some point byte ordering was changed as dmidecode man page says. The workaround for these may be getting UUID from /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid