# Check memory channel and count physical RAM in Linux with C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to check the number of channels and the count of RAM installed in a system. Currently dmidecode lets me do that. For example:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type memory
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.

Handle 0x005B, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 128 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0066, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: SODIMM1
    Bank Locator: Channel 0 Slot 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Crucial Technology
    Serial Number: E55FEE6B
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CB8GS2666.C8RT      
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2667 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 6, Hex 0x9B
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 8 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0067, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x005B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8 GB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: SODIMM2
    Bank Locator: Channel 0 Slot 0
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Crucial Technology
    Serial Number: E56002E0
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CB8GS2666.C8RT      
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2667 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Bank 6, Hex 0x9B
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 8 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None
```

I can filter the data for sure. But each dmidecode is a separate spawned process. And the user can call the function a lot of times depending on their system (please don't suggest spawning dmidecode and memoizing the value).

The main goal is to also to be fast as possible. Is there a way to get such details from within a C program assuming no linux-header is installed?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214171/c-c-api-for-dmidecode

Comment: Could always just poke around in the [dmidecode source code](https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode).